# How to add volume control to basic amplifier circuit

Tags: amplifier, audio

What is the best way to add a volume control POT to this circuit?  It is based on an LM4871, and the datasheet is located here: [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm4871.pdf)

[image: LM4871]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace Rf with a 20k pot set up as a variable resistor. The output will be proportional to the resistance.

Comment: Thank you!  This worked perfectly!